# Puppet Exec resource to apply only when a File changes

Tags: puppet

I have two Puppet Resource Types, a File and an Exec:

```puppet
file { 'folder_a':
  source  => 'puppet:///modules/folder_a',
  ensure  => 'directory',
  recurse => true,
  path    => 'C:/folder_a',
  source_permissions => ignore,
  notify  => Exec['install.bat'],
}

exec { 'test_cmd':
  path      => $::path,
  command   => 'cmd.exe /c C:/test.cmd',
  provider  => windows,
  subscribe => File['folder_a'],
  logoutput => true,
}
```

If the File Resource doesn't apply, I don't want the Exec Resource to run either. But if the source files are updated, then the Exec should run.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As noted in the [docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-refreshonly) for the Exec type, there is the `refreshonly` attribute:

> **refreshonly**
>
> The command should only be run as a refresh mechanism for when a dependent object is changed.

It sounds like this is exactly what you need:

```puppet
exec { 'test_cmd':
  path      => $::path,
  command   => 'cmd.exe /c C:/test.cmd',
  provider  => windows,
  subscribe => File['folder_a'],
  logoutput => true,
  refreshonly => true, # Add this line.
}
```

Keep in mind that [some](http://ffrank.github.io/misc/2015/05/26/friends-don%27t-let-friends-use-refreshonly/) strongly recommend `refreshonly` to be used as a last resort only.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I added the line to the EXEC and I delete the Folder_a from the Destination, after that I run puppet agent -t  it create the Folder_a again but the exec doesnt run test.cmd file, why?

I make also changes to the Folder_a but it still dont run EXEC

Comment: I don't know what you mean by you deleted the Folder_a from the Destination or why you did that?